# Serving permitted documents in microservices environment

Tags: node.js, architecture, microservices

Lets assume the following scenario :

- There is an undefined number of micro-services written in node.js on top of the database
- There is a Front-end application consuming those services using token based authentication and expanded Actor pattern for permissions
- Certain requests are required to return documents
- Those documents may only be served to users with permissions for specific document (permissions are app based, not OS based)
- Microservice endpoint fetches document info from DB which would contain a path to the document on file server, that path would be resolved by service consumer application which would then serve the actual document.

With these things in mind, i'm trying to figure out safest and fastest way  (performance wise) to enable my system with abilities to download and upload documents.

This approach still uses the built in permission system to obtain document physical path (not the doc it self) but trust needs to exist between consumer server and File server to obtain the actual document.
**File server is in no way exposed to internet.**

EDIT: 
If as per @JPs suggestion i decided to go with document storage exposed to internet, i'm affraid that in case of front-end being compromised attacker would be able to get any document he wants.

I'm unsure if thats the way to go especially if there is a way to avoid any kind of trust and be as explicit as possible, but i'm hoping someone will be able to suggest better way or the right way of achieving this.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I think the best solution for you is to distance yourself from the managing the uploads, especially if scale is a concern of yours.

In my opinion, I think using S3 is your best option, specifically levering it's POST object callbacks, https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/UsingHTTPPOST.html

By doing this you can have users upload documents directly to S3 rather than having your server be the middleman, then you can get the file and manipulate it after your server is notified of the objects presence in the S3 bucket.

When it comes to downloading, you should also just serve the files directly from S3. You can use signed requests along with CloudFront to prevent the user from poking around your S3 buckets. You will still have to check a DB for permissions for the file in question, there is no way around this unless you somehow embed the permissions in the users session or something else.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, i've edited my question slightly to answer your questions and avoid confusion. This is purely architectural question, so i'm looking for potential alternative solutions (safer, faster, better in any way) in how to approach the problem.

Comment: I've updated my answer, im still unclear of what the premise of your question is, what you're asking is pretty trivial, but the question of "fastest" or "safest" doesn't make a lot of sense to me.

Comment: See moving document storage to s3 actually exposes documents to internet which i wanted to avoid. In my scenario document storage is never exposed to internet, and the service serving documents needs to talk to underlying microservice layer first, get authorized for the resource and then  get the actual document. So i need to have a look at your proposed signed requests. If you explain how that works, tht might be the valuable part of answer i'm looking for.